# Linq to entities - Formatting results

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm having problem to format the results of a linq query

## Code

```
var listOfCustomerSearchResult = (from customer in entities.Customers
        where customer.Number.StartsWith(customerNumber)
        select new CustomerSearchResult
        {
            AccountNbr = (customer.Number.IndexOf(".") > 0) ? customer.Number.Substring(0, customer.Number.IndexOf(".")) : customer.Number,
            SubAccountNbr = (customer.Number.IndexOf(".") > 0) ? customer.Number.Substring(customer.Number.IndexOf(".") + 1) : string.Empty,
            FirstAndLastName = (customer.Contact.IsIndividual) ? (customer.Contact.FirstNameCareOf + " " ?? string.Empty) + (customer.Contact.Name ?? string.Empty) : (customer.Contact.Name ?? string.Empty) + " " + (customer.Contact.FirstNameCareOf ?? string.Empty),
            StreetAddress = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().StreetAddress ?? string.Empty,
            City = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().City ?? string.Empty,
            ZipCode = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().ZipCode ?? string.Empty,
            Region = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Region.Code ?? string.Empty,
            Delivery = string.Empty,
            IsActive = customer.IsActive,
            IsAdministrative = customer.IsAdministrative,
            SearchStep = 1,
            CustomerId = customer.Id,
            AccountType = customer.Type.EnumId,
            Phone = customer.Contact.Phones.FirstOrDefault().Number ?? string.Empty

        }).Take(500).ToList();
```

## Questions

1- I need to format the address, phone etc but i cant be done directly in the Select new...   Is there a way to call my "helper fonction" (like FormatPhoneNumber(), FormatAddress(), ...) without scanning all the results and format each result one by one after executing the query?  ex: Like MyQuery...blabla...Take(500).ToList().ImaginaryFormatProperties(x=> x.Phone = FormatPhone(x.Phone), x.Address = FormatAddress(x.Address) ...

2- I need to call this query many many time with tons of different WHERE clause each time.  Is there a way to do this without having to create the CustomerSearchResult and assign every properties like this each time ???   I dont want to repeat this setting part each time since it's not changing

Thanks!

Comment: 2: Expand the where clause with predicates, so you have this query only in one place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)
You could add a readonly property to your CustomerSearchResult model class to do the formatting for you.

```
public class CustomerSearchResult
{
    //All of your current properties in this class  here


    //New readonly Property
    public string PhoneFormatedString
    {
        get
        {
            return //Do your formatting here using the Phone property, or pass it to a function
        }
    }
}
```

2.) You want to create an IQueryable result like so.

```
    public IQueryable<CustomerSearchResult> CustomerSearchBaseQuery()
    {
        IQueryable<CustomerSearchResult> listOfCustomerSearchResult = (from customer in entities.Customers
                                          select new CustomerSearchResult
                                          {
                                              AccountNbr = (customer.Number.IndexOf(".") > 0) ? customer.Number.Substring(0, customer.Number.IndexOf(".")) : customer.Number,
                                              SubAccountNbr = (customer.Number.IndexOf(".") > 0) ? customer.Number.Substring(customer.Number.IndexOf(".") + 1) : string.Empty,
                                              FirstAndLastName = (customer.Contact.IsIndividual) ? (customer.Contact.FirstNameCareOf + " " ?? string.Empty) + (customer.Contact.Name ?? string.Empty) : (customer.Contact.Name ?? string.Empty) + " " + (customer.Contact.FirstNameCareOf ?? string.Empty),
                                              StreetAddress = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().StreetAddress ?? string.Empty,
                                              City = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().City ?? string.Empty,
                                              ZipCode = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().ZipCode ?? string.Empty,
                                              Region = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Region.Code ?? string.Empty,
                                              Delivery = string.Empty,
                                              IsActive = customer.IsActive,
                                              IsAdministrative = customer.IsAdministrative,
                                              SearchStep = 1,
                                              CustomerId = customer.Id,
                                              AccountType = customer.Type.EnumId,
                                              Phone = customer.Contact.Phones.FirstOrDefault().Number ?? string.Empty

                                          });

        return listOfCustomerSearchResult;
    }
```

And then you can query from your IQueryable. Sql is not executed until you call ToList()

```
    public List<CustomerSearchResult> CustomerSearchByNumber(string customerNumber)
    {
        return CustomerSearchBaseQuery().Where(x => x.AccountNbr.StartsWith(customerNumber)).ToList();
    }
```

EDIT 1: Based on your comment try what you need to do using a Func

```
//Customer here is the class from your entity model
    public static Expression<Func<Customer, CustomerSearchResult>> customerSelector = (customer) =>
    new CustomerSearchResult
    {
        AccountNbr = (customer.Number.IndexOf(".") > 0) ? customer.Number.Substring(0, customer.Number.IndexOf(".")) : customer.Number,
        SubAccountNbr = (customer.Number.IndexOf(".") > 0) ? customer.Number.Substring(customer.Number.IndexOf(".") + 1) : string.Empty,
        FirstAndLastName = (customer.Contact.IsIndividual) ? (customer.Contact.FirstNameCareOf + " " ?? string.Empty) + (customer.Contact.Name ?? string.Empty) : (customer.Contact.Name ?? string.Empty) + " " + (customer.Contact.FirstNameCareOf ?? string.Empty),
        StreetAddress = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().StreetAddress ?? string.Empty,
        City = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().City ?? string.Empty,
        ZipCode = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().ZipCode ?? string.Empty,
        Region = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Region.Code ?? string.Empty,
        Delivery = string.Empty,
        IsActive = customer.IsActive,
        IsAdministrative = customer.IsAdministrative,
        SearchStep = 1,
        CustomerId = customer.Id,
        AccountType = customer.Type.EnumId,
        Phone = customer.Contact.Phones.FirstOrDefault().Number ?? string.Empty
    };
```

And then your query would look like

```
var listOfCustomerSearchResult = entities.Customers.Where(x => x.Number.StartsWith(customerNumber)).Select(customerSelector).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks seems like exactly what I need.... but.....the problem with that solution is the object "customer" is not available in CustomerSearchByNumber.   ex: when trying to create a CustomerSearchByContactName I cant access to customer.contact.name since customer is in the other method (customerSearchBaseQuery)  is there a way to access to customer.contact in the CustomerSearchBy.. () method?

Comment: I edited my response. Look at the EDIT 1 section and try giving that a try.

Comment: Thanks Travis!    My issue was solved by using the func method to assign the properties at only one place.   Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to collect this extra information using an anonymous type. For example:

```
var listOfCustomerSearchResult = (from customer in entities.Customers
        where customer.Number.StartsWith(customerNumber)
        select new { CustomerSearchResult = new CustomerSearchResult
        {
            AccountNbr = (customer.Number.IndexOf(".") > 0) ? customer.Number.Substring(0, customer.Number.IndexOf(".")) : customer.Number,
            SubAccountNbr = (customer.Number.IndexOf(".") > 0) ? customer.Number.Substring(customer.Number.IndexOf(".") + 1) : string.Empty,
            FirstAndLastName = (customer.Contact.IsIndividual) ? (customer.Contact.FirstNameCareOf + " " ?? string.Empty) + (customer.Contact.Name ?? string.Empty) : (customer.Contact.Name ?? string.Empty) + " " + (customer.Contact.FirstNameCareOf ?? string.Empty),
            StreetAddress = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().StreetAddress ?? string.Empty,
            City = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().City ?? string.Empty,
            ZipCode = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().ZipCode ?? string.Empty,
            Region = customer.Contact.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Region.Code ?? string.Empty,
            Delivery = string.Empty,
            IsActive = customer.IsActive,
            IsAdministrative = customer.IsAdministrative,
            SearchStep = 1,
            CustomerId = customer.Id,
            AccountType = customer.Type.EnumId,
            Phone = customer.Contact.Phones.FirstOrDefault().Number ?? string.Empty

        }, FormatedPhone = FormatPhone(customer.Phone), ... ).Take(500).ToList();
```

This will give you access to these additional properties without performing a search through your query.